# I have trouble in connecting to the mongodb database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backend, mern, web-frontend

When compiled the mongodb is successfully connected but when it comes to a particular page, Donation page the data entered by the user is not collected in the database.

this is how I created a schema for my page

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  const donationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    
  });


module.exports = mongoose.model("donations", donationSchema);
```

this the router code for the page

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
  const donation = require('../models/donation');
  const authMiddleware = require("../middlewares/authMiddleware");

  router.post('/donate',authMiddleware,async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { name, phoneNumber, amount } = req.body;

      // Create a new donation instance
      const newDonation = new donation({
        name,
        phoneNumber,
        amount,
      });

      // Save the donation to the database
      await newDonation.save();

      return res.send(200).json({ message: 'Donation submitted successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.send(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
    }
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

In the frontend inside the api calls folder created another js file

```
  import axios from "axios";

  export const DonateBook = async (donationData) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/donate", donationData);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.error);
    }
  };
```

Also in the frontend inside the components folder created the javascript file for Donation page

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DonateBook } from '../apicalls/donatebook';
//import axios from "axios";
const DonationPage = () => 
{
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
  //const [error,setError] =useState(null)
  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePhoneNumberChange = (e) => {
    setPhoneNumber(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAmountChange = (e) => {
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    alert("Submitted successfully");
    // setName('');
    // setPhoneNumber('');
    // setAmount('');
    e.preventDefault();
   

    try {
        DonateBook({name,phoneNumber,amount});
      // Perform API call to store the donation details in the database
//         name,
      //  phoneNumber,
       //  amount,
     // });

      // Clear form inputs after successful submission
      setName('');
      setPhoneNumber('');
      setAmount('');

      // Refresh the page to show updated donation information
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


  return (
    < div classname="h-screen bg-white p-3 rounded flex items-center justify-center ">
     <h1 className="text-secondary  text-2xl bg-white p-3 rounded font-bold mb-1 text-center">WELCOME TO THE BOOK DONATION PAGE</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ maxWidth: '400px', margin: '0 auto' }} layout="vertical">
        <div className="mb-3 text-center  ">
          <span className="gap-2">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label  gap-1">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control "
            id="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
            required
          />
          </span>
        
        
        <label htmlFor="phoneNumber" className='form-label gap-1 p-3'>Phone Number</label>
        <input
          type="tel"
          id="phoneNumber"
          value={phoneNumber}
          onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
          required
        />
        

        <label htmlFor="amount">Donation Amount</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="amount"
          value={amount}
          onChange={handleAmountChange}
          required
        />

        <div>
          <h3>Scan the provided QR code to make your payment:</h3>
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MpYBxGG6/Screenshot-20230619-182919-GPay.jpg" alt="QR Code" height={"200px"} width={"250px"} />

        </div>

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
          
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DonationPage;
```

Comment: Have you included the JSON body-parsing middleware `app.use(express.json())`?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I don't see where you connect to the MongoDB database.

Comment: In the handleSubmit function, try awaiting the call to DonateBook before reloading the page.